# How to speed up QGIS browser opening directory?

Tags: qgis

If the directory containing many raster files, QGIS browser is very slow?
I think the program is scaning all files which take much times. Are there any setting accelerate this process?

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to quantify the number after raster and provide timing in seconds. You should also provide information about the computer platform and the type of disk (HDD vs SSD vs USB). Generally, any GUI needs to read the TIFF header to confirm a valid file before displaying the image icon.

Comment: Was there ever anymore update to this question in regards of speeding it up? I am now using QGIS 3.10 and have raster support from within my browser panel which is very very slow in relation to the DB manager. I am using it to read over 40 LiDAR tiles and in browser the loading of the tables takes a good 60 secs, whereas the opening time in DB manager to view the tables is almost instant