# QGIS very slow when browsing files on macOS

Tags: qgis, performance, mac

QGIS is performing very slowly for me when browsing files and folders recently. I am running macOS Mojave and have no performance issues within QGIS, apart from the times I need to open or save a file.

I'm running the latest QGIS (3.4.4) as of 29/01/2019

I thought [this issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299832/how-to-speed-up-qgis-browser-opening-directory) may have been related, but the slowness of the finder window applies no matter which folders I am navigating between.

I have tried uninstalling all the plugins I have one by one, but that did not resolve the issue. It is making it very frustrating to use QGIS because I need to wait every time I save a file.

Again, this is a recent issue and I have not yet worked out what changed that may have caused it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug was reported and a workaround that seems to work for affected MacOS users here:

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20381#note-60

The work around:

> On your Mac, go to "System Preferences"-> "Security & Privacy" -> "Privacy" -> "Accessibility", and disable QGIS. It worked for me. After that, starting QGIS from the Mac launchpad doesn't lead to frozen finder dialogues.

Comment: I can confirm that the above answer solved the issue I reported.